# Using gets command to sort array alphabetically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, gets

I am a Ruby noob and am simply trying to use the gets command to sort a array of words ("dog", "cat", "ape") should be entered individually by gets and become ("ape", "cat", "dog")

I have tried:

```
list = Object.new
list = []
word = STDIN.gets
list.push(word)
$/ = "END"
puts list
```

Any help would be great as this is to help my daughter sort her homework faster and learn to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also enter all the words at once if you want to:

```
>> words = gets.chomp.split(/,\s*/).sort
dog, cat,ape                             #=> ["ape", "cat", "dog"]
```

If you want to read them individually:

```
>> words = [] #=> []
>> until (word = gets.chomp).empty? do
..     words << word
..   end
cat
ape
dog
         #=> nil
>> words.sort #=> ["ape", "cat", "dog"]
```

That's just copy/paste from IRB, but easy enough to make into the program you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = []
until (word = gets.chomp) == "END"  do
  list << word
end

puts "Sorted Values:"
puts list.sort
```

This will take input until you give it "END" (you can change this as you wish).

I am calling [Array#sort](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000244)